# how to define my own tcp header options and how to make regular tcp server react to these options?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I want to build a specific proxy server and  corresponding specific client program. 
I want to define my own tcp header options. These tcp header options are only used by the proxy server and the client program.
I don't want to make the tcp header option universal.

I noticed that the TCP header option kind number 31-252 are not used.

http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/tcp.htm#Options

So I can choose from the range to define my own tcp header option, which is only used by my proxy program and client.

But the problem is, how can I make a regular tcp server to react to a tcp packet
with header options? For example, when I use something like:

```
 listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); 

 bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

 listen(listenfd,1024);

 connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);

 n = recvfrom(connfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen)
```

the tcp options are not carried in the `mesg` right?
So how to make the tcp server process my defined tcp options?

How is the tcp option negotiation done? for example, SACK.
What options are enabled by default on regular tcp servers?

Are there any source codes related to tcp header options?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to define my own tcp header options

Why?

---

> so I can choose from the range to define my own tcp header option

No. You will need to apply to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/) for one to be assigned to your proposed extension.

---

> but the problem is how can I make a regular tcp server to react to a tcp packet with header options?

If you mean by *regular* is what I understand as *regular* then the answer is: create and document an extension to TCP via the IETF [RFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) process. You will then need to get your proposal implemented in as many TCP stacks for as many operating systems as to meet your *regular* requirement. You will probably need your new TCP option to be adopted by the network interface card chipset manufacturers as well; much of TCP processing is off-loaded to the network card in many cases these days.

---

> how is the tcp option negotiation done? for example, SACK what options are enabled by default on regular tcp servers?

I fail to see how the second question here is an example of the first. However, from [RFC 2018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018):

> Generating Sack Options: Data Receiver Behavior
>
> If the data receiver has received a SACK-Permitted option on the SYN
> for this connection, the data receiver MAY elect to generate SACK
> options as described below.  If the data receiver generates SACK
> options under any circumstance, it SHOULD generate them under all
> permitted circumstances.  If the data receiver has not received a
> SACK-Permitted option for a given connection, it MUST NOT send SACK
> options on that connection.

---

> are there any source codes related to tcp header options?

There's a network stack in [Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/), which is Open Source.

---

Considering you're asking these questions, I suspect your ambition may outstrip your current capabilities.

Comment: so you mean there are different TCP stacks, nearly all TCP stacks support very common options, like SACK, timestamp, MSS, window scale, but some of the options in the lik: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/tcp.htm#Options are only supported by some TCP stacks?

Comment: BTW, I have modified my questions according to your answer

Comment: @misteryes: You still haven't explained why you think you need a new TCP option. What you have updated with contradicts what you originally posted.

Comment: it is for a research work, I want to build a proxy and the client needs to send some information to the proxy. Yes, I can use application layer. But the information bytes are  so small and it makes me wonder whether I need to define them as options

Comment: @misteryes: Modifying TCP is rarely the solution to a problem.